# ASP Core Razor Syntax @for -> multiple submitbuttons with diffrent inputs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i am trying to create a ASP Core Application with Razorpages.

Everything is working fine so far, but now i'm stuck with this problem:

I want to create a form with multiple Buttons based on a Objectarray. Each Button has its own Name and should call the same OnPost method. So far so good. I struggle with posting the correct Object with the form.

Here is some Code...

Test.cshtml :

```
@page
@using APP.Models
@model TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var bereiche = Bereich.getBereiche();
}


<div class="grid">
    <h1 class="center-text">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    <form method="post" class="center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Model" class="col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="button-group-vertical">

                @for (var i = 0; i < bereiche.Count; i++)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Model" value="@bereiche[i]" />
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-md button-group-vertical-item">@bereiche[i].name</button>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Bereich.cs in namespace Model

```
public enum Art
{
    Mitte, Beladen, Inspection, Kette
}

public class Bereich
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Art art { get; set; }

        public static List<Bereich> getBereiche()
        {
            var bereiche = new List<Bereich>
            {
                new Bereich() { name="Mitte", art = Art.Mitte},
                new Bereich(){name= "Beladen",art = Art.Beladen },
                new Bereich(){name = "Qualitätskontrolle",art = Art.Inspection},
                new Bereich(){name ="Kette",art= Art.Kette}
            };

            return bereiche;
        }
    }
```

Test.cshtml.cs :

```
    public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Bereich")]
        [BindProperty]
        public Bereich Model { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            return Page(); // BREAKPOINT HERE -> MODEL always "art=Mitte", "name=null" :/
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue what i am doin wrong ?

Comment: The model is `{ art = Mitte, name = null }` because those are the two default values for those properties in your `Bereich` model. You shouldn’t attempt to post complex objects; that’s usually going to fail. Instead, post some identifier in the form and then use that to resolve the correct `Bereich` object on the server.

Comment: @poke Ok i thought there would be another way, but thanks. I added a ID to Bereich - class and changed my button to something like this:
<button type="submit" asp-route-id="@item.id" class="btn btn-info btn-md button-group-vertical-item">@item.name</button> 
In PageModel i do lookup the Posted ID and get the coresponding Bereich Object

Answer (score 2):

In order to post an object back, you could use one form per object, with named fields corrosponding to your object property names.

Try this instead:

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < bereiche.Count; i++)
{
    <form method="post" class="center">
        <input name="art" type="hidden" value="@bereiche[i].art" />
        <button name="name" value="@bereiche[i].name" class="btn btn-info">@bereiche[i].name</button>
    </form>
}
```

And also if you want your button to hold a value, you need to put the value in a value tag like i did in the example.

Comment: Ok this would work in this scope, but i want to add multiple Objects to the form i have already. If i do multiple forms this will messup my Layout. I´ll accept awnser from @poke